# Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous function on a metric space $E$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x_n)=f(x)$ for every $x_n\to x$ and $x\in E $ .

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

> Let $E$ be a metric space where every point of $E$ is an accumulation point. Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous function on $E$ and $$\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x_n)=f(x)$$ for every sequence of point $x_n \in E$ such that $x_n\to x$ and $x_n\neq x $ . Can we have $f_n \to f $ pointwisely or uniformly ?

My attempt:
Let $E=(0,1]$ and $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} n ,  0 < x < \frac1n \\
      \frac1x  ,  \frac{1}{n} \le x \le 1 \end{cases}$$
Then we can easily see $f_n(x)$ satisfied the hypothesis above and $f_n \to \frac1x$ , but converges not uniformly .

My question :
$(1)$ Can we construct $\{f_n\}$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x) \neq f(x)$ for some $x \in E$
$(2)$ If we assume $E$ is compact , can we show that $f_n \to f$ pointwisely or uniformly ?

Comment: Take $x_n\equiv x$, then we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$, $\forall x\in E$...

Comment: Maybe I should add $x_n \neq x$ in the post , If we can take $x_n = x$ , the question looks much simple .

Comment: You cannot require $x_n\ne x$, otherwise, consider $E=\{0\}\cup [1,2]\subset\mathbb R^1$. Then any continuous function on $[1,2]$ is also continuous on $E$ and we can revise the value at $0$ to whatever we like. Thus, there is no limitation to the value at $0$. Take $f_n(0)\equiv 0$ and a function $f$ continuous on $[1,2]$ and set $f(0)\equiv 1$. Apparently, $f_n(x_n)\to f(x)$ for every $x_n\to x$, $x_n\ne x$, but $f_n(x)$ does not pointwise converge to $f(x)$.

Comment: I can't see from your question that $f(x)$ is defined this way. If so, you have to check $f(x)$ is well-defined. But you didn't show that $f(x)$ is well-defined.

Comment: Or, if $E$ is discrete, then the assumption is vacuously satisfied (because there do not exist any sequences with $x_n \to x$ and $x_n \ne x$) and the functions $f_n$ can be anything at all, and need not converge in any way.

Comment: @Bach I see the point now , there's no sequence converges to $0$ , so we can take the value of $f(0)$ as we want .

Comment: @J.Guo I thought if you add another condition that every point of $E$ is an accumulation point, $f_n$ pointwisely converges and if $E$ is compact $f_n$ uniformly converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, under your hypothesis $(f_n(x))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ could diverge.

But if you add another condition that **every point of $E$ is an [accumulation point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point)**, we can say

> 1. $f_n \to f $ pointwisely.

**Proof** $\,\,$   Suppose for contradiction, then we have $\exists$ $\varepsilon_0 >0$, $\forall$ $N$, $\exists$ $n\ge N$, such that $d\left(f_n(x),f(x)\right)\ge \varepsilon_0$ for some $x \in E$, and hence we can find a strictly increasing sequence $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $d(f_{n_k}(x),f(x))\ge \varepsilon_0$.

Considering that $x$ is an accumulation point and that $f_n$ is continuous, we can find a sequence $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \to x$ such that $d(f_{n_k}(x_k),f(x))\ge \frac{\varepsilon_0}{2}$ , which contradicts the hypothesis $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x_n) = f(x)$ for every $x_n \to x$ (because the subsequence of a convergent sequence still converges to its limit).

> 2. $f$ is continuous.

**Proof** $\,\,$ Suppose $(x_k)$ converges to $x$ and let $\varepsilon>0$. From proposition 1, we can choose a strictly increasing sequence $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $ d(f(x_k),f_{n_k}(x_k))<\varepsilon$ for every $k$. The hypothesis that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x_n) = f(x)$ for every $x_n \to x$ implies $\lim_{k\to\infty} f_{n_k}(x_k) = f(x)$.

Note that
$
d(f(x_k),f(x))
\le d(f(x_k),f_{n_k}(x_k))+d(f_{n_k}(x_k),f(x))
$ thus there exists $N$ such that $\forall n > N$ $d(f(x_n),f(x)) < 2 \varepsilon$. Thus $f$ is continuous.

> 3. If $E$ is compact, then $f_n \to f$ uniformly.

**Proof** $\,\,$ Suppose for contradiction, then we can find a strictly increasing sequence $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ and a sequence $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that for every $k$, $d(f_{n_k}(x_k),f(x_k))\ge \varepsilon_0$ for some positive constant $\varepsilon_0$.

Since $E$ is a compact metric space, then $E$ is [limit point compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point_compact). Note that the points that appear in $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ can't be finitely many, otherwise it would contradict proposition 1, and hence $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ has an accumulation point, say $x$. Without loss of generality we suppose $x_k \to x$. Thus we have $\lim_{k\to\infty} f_{n_k}(x_k) = f(x)$.

Form proposition 2 we have $\lim_{k\to\infty} f(x_k) = f(x)$. Thus there exist $N$ such that $\forall n > N$ we have $d (f_{n_k}(x_k) ,f(x)) <\frac{\varepsilon_0}{2}$ and $d (f(x_k) ,f(x)) <\frac{\varepsilon_0}{2}$, which contradicts $d(f_{n_k}(x_k),f(x_k))\ge \varepsilon_0$.

Comment: I think $f_{n_k}(x_k)$ is not a subsequence of $f_k(x_k)$ , so how to show that $d(f_{n_k}(x_k),f(x))\ge \frac{\varepsilon_0}{2}$ lead to a contradication ?

Comment: @J.Guo Consider the sequence $(y_n)$
$$(y_n)=
(\underbrace{x_1,x_1,\ldots,x_1}_{n_1\text{-terms}}\,,\,
\underbrace{x_2,x_2,\ldots,x_2}_{n_2-n_1\text{-terms}}\,,\,
\underbrace{x_3,x_3,\ldots,x_3}_{n_3- n_2 \text{-terms}},\ldots).
$$ 
Since this sequence converges to $x$, we have $f_n(y_n)\rightarrow f(x)$. Thus $f_{n_k}(y_{n_k})=f_{n_k}(x_k)\rightarrow f(x)$. Then the contradiction is obvious.